# Simulate Mouse Clicks on Python

Tags: python, linux, mouse, mouse-cursor, wiimote

I'm currently in the process of making my Nintendo Wiimote (Kinda sad actually) to work with my computer as a mouse. I've managed to make the nunchuk's stick control actually move the mouse up and down, left and right on the screen! This was so exciting. Now I'm stuck.

I want to left/right click on things via python when I press A, When I went to do a search, All it came up with was tkinter?

So my question is, What do I call to make python left/right click on the desktop, and if it's possible, maybe provide a snippet?

Thank you for your help!

NOTE: I guess I forgot to mention that this is for Linux.

Comment: This will be OS/windowing system dependent probably. Ideally, there will be python bindings to your operating systems windowing system. Normally, the arguments are pretty similar to the C/C++/C#/Objective-C calls that the documentation is actually written in. Or you might luck out and have actual python docs. At least post what OS you're on so people can help.

Comment: Probably this answer is not relevant but maybe you could check Sikuli project source. It is jython but...

Comment: Looks like a nice project.. what are you using to move the mouse?
Are you doing that via Python, or in another way? And, of course, on which OS/DE/WM?
Btw, some times ago, I found a Xorg driver that should allow to use the Wiimote as a mouse (for the ir-pen interactive whiteboard project), maybe it could do the job..?

Comment: I'm moving the mouse with libX11 on python. I can't use IR so this is why i need to be able to click.

Comment: http://github.com/msanders/autopy#readme  This came up on another question and it simulates mouseclicks. Maybe you can look and see how they do it.

Answer (score 35):

You can use [PyMouse](https://github.com/pepijndevos/PyMouse) which has now merged with [PyUserInput](https://github.com/SavinaRoja/PyUserInput). I installed it via pip:

1. `apt-get install python-pip`
2. `pip install pymouse`

In some cases it used the cursor and in others it simulated mouse events without the cursor.

```
from pymouse import PyMouse

m = PyMouse()
m.position() #gets mouse current position coordinates
m.move(x,y)
m.click(x,y) #the third argument "1" represents the mouse button
m.press(x,y) #mouse button press
m.release(x,y) #mouse button release
```

You can also specify which mouse button you want used. Ex left button:

```
m.click(x,y,1)
```

Keep in mind, on Linux it requires Xlib.

Comment: Pymouse ```ModuleNotFoundError: No module named unix ``` Try installing ```pynput```

Comment: The most qualified successor of pymouse is `pyuserinput`

Answer (score 4):

The [evdev](http://packages.python.org/evdev/) package provides bindings to parts of the input handling subsystem in Linux. It also happens to include a pythonic interface to uinput.

Example of sending a relative motion event and a *left mouse click* with [evdev](http://packages.python.org/evdev/):

```
from evdev import UInput, ecodes as e

capabilities = {
    e.EV_REL : (e.REL_X, e.REL_Y), 
    e.EV_KEY : (e.BTN_LEFT, e.BTN_RIGHT),
}

with UInput(capabilities) as ui:
    ui.write(e.EV_REL, e.REL_X, 10)
    ui.write(e.EV_REL, e.REL_Y, 10)
    ui.write(e.EV_KEY, e.BTN_LEFT, 1)
    ui.syn()
```

Answer (score 4):

PyAutoGui works superb.. Thanks to Al Sweigart...

An example of mine...

```
import pyautogui

pyautogui.FAILSAFE = False

for x in range(555, 899):
    pyautogui.moveTo(x, x)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can install the PyAutoGUI GUI automation module from PyPI (run `pip install pyautogui`) and then call the `pyautogui.click()` to click on a certain X and Y coordinates of the screen:

```
>>> import pyautogui
>>> pyautogui.click(50, 100)
>>> pyautogui.moveTo(200, 200)
```

PyAutoGUI works on Windows, Mac, and Linux, and on Python 2 and 3. It also can emulate the keyboard, do mouse drags, take screenshots, and do simple image recognition of the screenshots.

Full docs are at https://pyautogui.readthedocs.org/

Answer (score 1):

Open your terminal and goto <kbd>cd /usr/share/pyshared/twisted/protocols/mice</kbd>
may this `__init__.py` `mouseman.py` python script will work for you,check them out.

Answer (score -1):

I didn't see this mentioned, so here it goes - there is also `python-dogtail`; see:

- [Automated GUI testing with Dogtail | Red Hat](http://www.redhat.com/magazine/020jun06/features/dogtail/)
- [Testing/Automation/DogtailTutorial - Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Testing/Automation/DogtailTutorial)

It requires "Enable assistive technologies" in the Gnome Desktop - but can in principle obtain e.g. names of GUI buttons of an application, and allow virtual clicks on them (rather than via x/y coordinates).