# How do I simulate mouse clicks with Xlib on Python

Tags: python, xlib, wiimote

For educational purposes I've set out to write a python script using `cwiid` and `Xlib` so that I can use my wiimote like a mouse.

So far I've gotten the cursor to move by calling `disp.warp_pointer(dx,dy)` then calling `disp.sync()` every set time interval. I'm afraid that it might not be the most efficient way to do it but at least for now, it's simple and works well enough.

The problem I'm having more difficulty with is mouse clicks. How do I simulate a mouse click in Xlib? I would like separate press and release events so that I can drag and drop stuff. I've come across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3545230/simulate-mouse-clicks-on-python) post, but all of the solutions there seem to use other libraries.

Comment: The [python-uinput suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3572488/709852) on the question you linked to should work. As I understand it, that's actually injecting events in at the kernel level, so it doesn't matter whether you're using XLib or Tkinter or GTK or any other toolkit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On plain Xlib (C language), you can use the `XTestExtension` or `XSendEvent()`. I'm not sure about their python bindings. There are probably bindings for their xcb versions using `xpyb`.

There's also a binary called `xte` from the `xautomation` package (on Debian, `sudo apt-get install xautomation` and then `man xte`). `xte` is very easy to use, and you can also look at its source code to learn how to use the `XTestExtension`.

Pointers:

- http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/lib/libXtst/
- http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xcb/xpyb/
- http://hoopajoo.net/projects/xautomation.html
- http://linux.die.net/man/1/xte

Comment: Upon further searching, it looks like `Xlib.ext.xtest` on Python may be equivalent to `XTestExtensions`. At any rate `xtest.fake_input` works great.

Comment: @math4tots: Thanks for your comment, I was trying to accomplish the same but I couldn't find how to call XTest* methods. Regards,

Answer (score 7):

using only python Xlib :

```
from Xlib import X
from Xlib.display import Display
from Xlib.ext.xtest import fake_input
d = Display()
fake_input(d, X.ButtonPress, 1)
d.sync()
fake_input(d, X.ButtonRelease, 1)
d.sync()
```

The third parameter to `fake_input` selects the mouse button being simulated. 1/2/3 being left/middle/right buttons, 4/5 and 6/7 should do vertical and horizontal wheel scrolls.