# Simulating Mouse Clicks In C With libX11

Tags: c, linux, x11, xorg

I know you can use XWrapPointer() to move the pointer, but how can I simulate clicks

Comment: Does using XSendEvent to send mouse click and mouse release events work? See this example: https://gist.github.com/pioz/726474

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I simulate mouse clicks with Xlib on Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10257019/how-do-i-simulate-mouse-clicks-with-xlib-on-python)