# How can I click somewhere without having a mouse plugged in with Python?

Tags: python

I want to make a program which clicks something with Phyton. Simple.

My problem is, that pyautogui (a package) only works with a mouse plugged in because it takes over the mouse and sends input trough it. I can't use a mouse because the program runs on my server which can't have a mouse.
Im using Windows Server 2019

Is there some package which can send inputs without a mouse plugged in? It would be very nice if someone could help me there.

Comment: Is this Windows?

Comment: its Windows Server 2019, sorry I forgot to say

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3545230/simulate-mouse-clicks-on-python

Comment: @JostB all off them are either outdated or not working :/

Answer (score 0):

Use the mouse module. Install with `pip install mouse`

```
import mouse

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mouse.move(200, 100)
    mouse.click(button='left')
```

Comment: This package takes over the mouse too so I sadly cant use it.